# Rabbitmq message sending error

Tags: erlang, message, rabbitmq

I try to send messsage to rabbitmq-server:

```
send_message(Channel, Host, Password, Message) ->
   amqp_channel:cast(Channel, #'basic.publish'{exchange = <<"">>},
                               routing_key = <<"test">>,
                              #amqp_msg{payload = Message}).
```

But get error:

```
Error in process <0.431.0> with exit value:
{function_clause,[{gen_server,cast, [2,{cast,{'basic.publish',0,<<0
bytes>>,<<7 bytes>>,false,false},
{amqp_msg,{'P_basic',undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined...
```

How can i fix it? How can i correctly send message to rabbitmq-server?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of the Erlang client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of *Channel*: from the stacktrace it shows that it is equal to **2**, which is not a valid Pid.

The code calling send_message/4 must do something funky and not pass a valid Channel to it.